# RecyclerView doesnt show in Navigation Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a navigation activity. In the file content.xml I have a recyclerview. If I put an EditText in the content.xml the recylerview is displayed, however if I do not put it it is not displayed.
I do not need the EditText field

Here are my code.

**content_navegador.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context="com.example.pablo.pruebasauthproyecto.Activities.Navegador"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_navegador">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Buscar Proyectos..."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/reciclador"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_text" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Navegador.java

> public class Navegador extends AppCompatActivity
>           implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
>
> ```
> public final static String PROYECTO = "proyecto";
>
> private RecyclerView recycler;
>
> private FirebaseUser fUsr;
> private String intereses;
> private String claveProy;
>
> private ArrayList<Proyecto> proyectos = new ArrayList<>();
> private ArrayList<String> listaIntereses = new ArrayList<>();
>
> final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
> Recursos r;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_navegador);
>     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
>     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
>
>     DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>     ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
>             this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
>     drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
>     toggle.syncState();
>
>     NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
>     navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
>
>     recuperarProyectos ();
> }
>
> private void recuperarInteresesUsuario() {
>     fUsr = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
>     DatabaseReference interesesRef = ref.child("intereses").child(fUsr.getUid());
>
>     interesesRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
>             intereses = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
>             listaIntereses.add(intereses);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> private void verProyecto(Proyecto proyecto) {
>     // Log.d("DEPURACIÓN", proyecto.toString());
>     Intent intent = new Intent(this, FichaProyecto.class);
>     intent.putExtra(this.PROYECTO, proyecto);
>     startActivity(intent);
> }
>
> private void cargarRecycler() {
>     // Obtener el Recycler
>     recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
>     recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
>
>     ProyectosAdapter adapter = new ProyectosAdapter(proyectos);
>
>     adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             // Log.d("DEPURACIÓN" , "Item Pulsado : " + proyectos.get(recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getNombre());
>             Proyecto prosel = proyectos.get(recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(view));
>             verProyecto(prosel);
>         }
>     });
>
>     recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
>
>     // Usar un administrador para LinearLayout
>     LinearLayoutManager lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
>     recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);
> }
>
> private void recuperarProyectos () {
>
>     DatabaseReference proyectosRef = ref.child("proyectos");
>     Query consProy = proyectosRef.orderByChild("genero");
>
>     consProy.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
>             claveProy = dataSnapshot.getKey();
>             final Proyecto p = dataSnapshot.getValue(Proyecto.class);
>             for (String inter : listaIntereses) {
>                 // Log.d("DEPURACIÓN", inter);
>                 if(p.getGenero().equalsIgnoreCase(inter)) {
>                     // Log.d("DEPURACIÓN", p.toString());
>                     DatabaseReference recursosRef = ref.child("recursos");
>                     Query consRecursos = recursosRef.orderByChild("idProyecto").equalTo(claveProy);
>                     consRecursos.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
>                         @Override
>                         public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
>                             r = dataSnapshot.getValue(Recursos.class);
>                             // Log.d("DEPURACIÓN","PROYECTO -> " + p.toString());
>                             p.addRecurso(r);
>                             // Log.d("DEPURACIÓN", "RECURSOS PROYECTO -> " + p.getRecursos().toString());
>                             proyectos.add(p);
>                             // eliminamos elementos repetidos del ArrayList
>                             HashSet<Proyecto> hs = new HashSet<>();
>                             hs.addAll(proyectos);
>                             proyectos.clear();
>                             proyectos.addAll(hs);
>                         }
>
>                         @Override
>                         public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
>
>                         }
>
>                         @Override
>                         public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>
>                         }
>
>                         @Override
>                         public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
>
>                         }
>
>                         @Override
>                         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>
>                         }
>                     });
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>
>         }
>     });
>
>     recuperarInteresesUsuario();
>
>     cargarRecycler();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onBackPressed() {
>     DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>     if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
>         drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
>     } else {
>         super.onBackPressed();
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navegador, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>     int id = item.getItemId();
>
>     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
>     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
> }
>
> @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
> @Override
> public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
>     int id = item.getItemId();
>
>     if (id == R.id.crear_proyect) {
>         startActivity(new Intent(Navegador.this, CrearProyecto.class));
>     } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
>
>     } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
>
>     } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
>
>     } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
>
>     } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
>
>     }
>
>     DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>     drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
>     return true;
> } }
> ```

**ProyectosAdapter.java**

> public class ProyectosAdapter extends
>   RecyclerView.Adapter implements
>   View.OnClickListener {
>
> ```
> private List<Proyecto> items;
> private View.OnClickListener listener;
>
> public class ProyectosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
>
>     public ImageView imagen;
>     public TextView nombre;
>     public TextView autor;
>     public TextView genero;
>
>     public ProyectosViewHolder(View v) {
>         super(v);
>         imagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
>         nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
>         autor = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.autor);
>         genero = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.genero);
>     }
> }
>
> public ProyectosAdapter(List<Proyecto> items) {
>     this.items = items;
> }
>
> @Override
> public int getItemCount() {
>     return items.size();
> }
>
> @Override
> public ProyectosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
>     View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
>             .inflate(R.layout.proyectos_card, viewGroup, false);
>
>     v.setOnClickListener(this);
>
>     return new ProyectosViewHolder(v);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onBindViewHolder(final ProyectosViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
>     viewHolder.nombre.setText(items.get(i).getNombre());
>     viewHolder.autor.setText(items.get(i).getAutor());
>     viewHolder.genero.setText(items.get(i).getGenero());
>
>     Context context = viewHolder.imagen.getContext();
>     Uri uri = Uri.parse(items.get(i).getRecursos().get(0).getRuta());
>     Picasso.with(context)
>             .load(uri)
>             .resize(355,225)
>             .centerCrop()
>             .into(viewHolder.imagen);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onClick(View view) {
>     if(listener != null)
>         listener.onClick(view);
> }
>
> public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
>     this.listener = listener;
> } }
> ```

Comment: Can you share your Activity code? RecyclerView needs a LayoutManager to actually display anything

Comment: Edited! I Post my code Activity and Adapter code.

Comment: SOLVED! The problem is that it did not call the notifyDataSetChanged() method, that's why there were times when it worked and sometimes it did not. It had nothing to do with the Layout. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your constraints are messed up. For example your RecyclerView have `toBottomOf="@+id/search_text"`, so it expects that edit text to present.

Try to remove EditText, and instead of that last line add `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your RecyclerView width and height is 0dp.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reciclador"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! But doesnt work..If i show the EditText Activity shows ReciclerView if I delete the EditText doesnt works...

Comment: Delete EditText means hide?

Comment: I put an EditText to test..With the EditText it works without the no. Can it be a focus problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from recyclerview
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_text"

This is beacuse you have given top to bottom of edittext.. 
Change it like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:id="@+id/reciclador" 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" 
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: I put a EditText to test, if remove the EditText it doenst show the RecyclerView. Can it be a Focus Problem in the content.xml where the recyclerview is?

Answer (score 0):

Put `setAdapter` after `setLayoutManager`

Comment: The problem is that it did not call the notifyDataSetChanged() method, that's why there were times when it worked and sometimes it did not. It had nothing to do with the Layout. Thank you all!